# Create Hints flyout when clicking on help icon

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to create the WPF effect of a Hints popup when hovering over or clicking a help icon at the end of a row.  Any ideas?  I tried something like this, except when I click the Flyout doesn't activate.

```
<TextBlock Text="?">
    <TextBlock.ContextFlyout>
        <Flyout>
            <RichTextBlock>
                <Paragraph>
                  This is the help <LineBreak/>
                  for this row<LineBreak/>
                </Paragraph>
            </RichTextBlock>
        </Flyout>
   </TextBlock.ContextFlyout>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: If you want to show only text it is better to use tooltip , else you can use pointer entered event on your text block to show flyout

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you could make [`AttachedFlyout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutbase.AttachedFlyoutProperty) in the `TextBlock` xaml like the follow:

```
<TextBlock Text="?" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <Flyout>
             <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="You can edit this text by tapping it."/>
        </Flyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>    
</TextBlock>
```

And invoke [`ShowAttachedFlyout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutbase.showattachedflyout#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_FlyoutBase_ShowAttachedFlyout_Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_) method in TextBlock `Tapped` event handler.

```
private void Element_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
    if (element != null)
    {
        FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(element);
    }
}
```

You could also use [`ToolTip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tooltips) to achieve it.

```
<TextBlock Text="?">
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
<ToolTip Content="You can edit this text by tapping it." />
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```